# PHP custom class objects and POST

Tags: php, class, session, post, cookies

I am trying to understand PHP login system using this [php-login-advanced](https://github.com/panique/php-login-advanced) by panique. The code snippet for [register.php](https://github.com/panique/php-login-advanced/blob/master/register.php) is:

```
<?php

// check for minimum PHP version
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<')) {
    exit('Sorry, this script does not run on a PHP version smaller than 5.3.7 !');
} else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<')) {
    // if you are using PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 you have to include the password_api_compatibility_library.php
    // (this library adds the PHP 5.5 password hashing functions to older versions of PHP)
    require_once('libraries/password_compatibility_library.php');
}
// include the config
require_once('config/config.php');

// include the to-be-used language, english by default. feel free to translate your project and include something else
require_once('translations/en.php');

// include the PHPMailer library
require_once('libraries/PHPMailer.php');

// load the registration class
require_once('classes/Registration.php');

// create the registration object. when this object is created, it will do all registration stuff automatically
// so this single line handles the entire registration process.
$registration = new Registration();

// showing the register view (with the registration form, and messages/errors)
include("views/register.php");
```

and in class Registration the constructor is:

```
public function __construct()
{
    session_start();

    // if we have such a POST request, call the registerNewUser() method
    if (isset($_POST["register"])) {
        $this->registerNewUser($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_password_new'], $_POST['user_password_repeat'], $_POST["captcha"]);
    // if we have such a GET request, call the verifyNewUser() method
    } else if (isset($_GET["id"]) && isset($_GET["verification_code"])) {
        $this->verifyNewUser($_GET["id"], $_GET["verification_code"]);
    }
}
```

On line `$registration = new Registration();` a new object of type Registration is created and it's constructor is called on Server-Side. The Server calls **session_start()** function. If a valid Session-ID was sent by client then file corresponding to that Session-ID is loaded in **$_SESSION** variable or else a new Session-ID is generated and is sent to client to store that in a **COOKIE** to maintain the session. The rendered register.php page is sent to client. Client fills form and submits. The values of form get stored in the **$_POST** array on Server-Side and this time when NEW object of class Registration is created the other two lines are also executed and the user is registered.

My Question is:
Am I understanding correctly the lifetime of **$_POST**, **$_SESSION** and the **Registration** Object? A better explanation is most welcome.